# error: use of undeclared identifier 'Solution' vector<int> ret = Solution().plusOne(param_1); return ret;

Tags: c++, xcode, codeigniter, cppcheck, cppunit

**trying to add +1 to the nth term****and showing the error at the leetcode window which is mentioned above**

```
     #include<iostream>

     using namespace std;
     int main()
   {
         int n;
         int a[n];//array of n number
         cin>>n;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        cin>>a[i];
     }
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      if(a[i+1]==a[n]) //I am trying to add +1 to nth term of array
        {
                a[i]=a[i]+1;
        
         }
        cout<<a[i];
          }
         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: It seems your code doesn't satisfy the question's requirements. Read the question carefully and implement according to that.

Comment: Try changing `int a[n];` with `std::vector<int> a(n);`. What your trying to do is illegal in C++ as your creating a static array. And to add one to the array, use `a.push_back()` method by pushing back the required data to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I think you might have erased all the code in leetcode window and pasted the above code in it. You might have erased
"***
Class Solution{
public:
};
***"
part of the console. Try to reset your code and paste your solution(which includes only the function) only under public section of the class. It should work fine.